# Keep order of request with fetch and async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I have a simple async function that sends data to the server.
This function is called by an external API and I don't have control over its execution.

The problem is that some requests are dependent on the previous ones so I have to keep the order of them, but this API can call the function on the same second with multiple requests and the requests arrive on the server in whatever order they want because of the async fetch API.

I need them to be sent in the exact same order as the API called them. So, in general, I need all the requests to be sent synchronously (I mean in the same order as they arrived) to the server but using an async method. How can I do that?

My code:

```js
function waitForAPICall() {
  sendDataToServer(params); //I don't need the response from server, I just want data to be sent
}

async function sendDataToServer(params) {
  const response = await fetch('url', {options});
  const temp = await response;
  return temp.json();
}
```

Comment: use then to get the result of promise, and in then call another api

Comment: I can't call another API, because the API call is not sent by me. I simply listen to the API and send the data to the server.

Comment: This problem cannot be solved client-side.  You can only solve the problem server-side, where the problem actually is.  The server should not return a response until it has completed its work.

Comment: @Brad the requests seem to come in the wrong order from the client-side on the server. The server waits for a request to finish and then processes another, but the arrival order is wrong.

Comment: Does this help?
`async function waitForAPICall() { await sendDataToServer(params); }`

Comment: TCP/IP packages can overtake each other while traveling through the internet. There is no garantee you will receive the messages in the order you sent them. If the messages themselves don't have a counter or ID of some sort it is hard to tell which order they should be processed in.